# Select the common item from the list of character vectors

Tags: r

I want to find the common characters from the list of character vectors. 
Below is the example through which problem can be solved. But i have list which has like 100 character vectors and i want to use for loop to iterate over the loop and get the common character items

```
ab <- c ("a", "b", "c", "g")
cd <- c("a" ,"d", "c", "e", "f")
ef <- c("a", "c", "i", "r", "t")
dat <- list(ab,cd,ef)

Reduce(intersect, dat)
[1] "a" "c"
```

Edit: My problem is i am having a large list with the character vectors nested in it. that is the reason i want to use `for` loop to iterate over the list and find the common items from the character vectors.

I tried something like this shown below but i am not getting any output

```
for (i in 1: seq_along(dat))
{
   op <- Reduce(intersect, dat[[i]])
}
```

Comment: A `for` loop would be much less efficient than the current (correct and encouraged) use of `Reduce`. What is wrong with doing it this way?

Comment: I have a large nested `list` which has 100 `character` `vectors`. and it is not possible to enter all 100 vectors manually into a list and calculate.

Comment: *"I have a large nested `list`"*, is there a reason you cannot run `Reduce` on this list? I think it would be easier to help you if you provided a representative sample of this nested list. (Anyway, whatever is difficult for `Reduce(intersect,...)` will likely be equally difficult for a nested list.)

Comment: I have edited the question. @r2evans

Comment: Do you mean something like `lapply(dat, function(smalllist) Reduce(intersect, smalllist))`?

Comment: The large `list` was generated using lapply. But, however i have solved the problem and posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used to solve the problem using the `for` loop:

```
ab <- c ("a", "b", "c", "g")
cd <- c("a" ,"d", "c", "e", "f")
ef <- c("a", "c", "i", "r", "t")
dat <- list(ab,cd,ef)

op <- vector()
for (i in seq_along(dat)) 
{
  op[i] <- list(dat[[i]])  
}
op.final <- Reduce(intersect, op)
```

Comment: the above code works perfectly fine and don't deserve an downvote !!.